# Only allow certain types for properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties

```
function Dude() {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
};

var d = new Dude();
d.firstName = 'Ok mr';
d.firstName = 100;
```

How do I prevent / guard the assignment of 100 to firstName so that it will always be a string? Assigning a number, array another object should convert to a string.

Comment: Is not posible at all, because you can always rewrite the value of any property of your object instance. But when you try to operate the value with another string, your value is always converted to their String representation, internally converting the value with de String() convertion function.

Comment: Use a getter/setter or use a method for changing the property and make the property be private.  See http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html for how to have private member variables that you control the access to via methods.  Keep in mind that javascript is not a typed language so the interpreter won't enforce a certain type - you have to use your own code to control access to the property.

Comment: I had this in mind first,

d.firstName(100), where I'm able to do this check, but I could not figure out how to get the value without the () in the d.firstName() since this will just return the function.

Comment: @Dilemmat_Dag - if you're willing to limit yourself to modern browsers, you can defined getters and setters for a property that let you control how the variable is set or retrieved.  See [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/) for an example.  You can find lots more info with a Google search for "getter setter javascript".

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for answers and guidelines. Regarding the defined getters and setters tutorial, seems like it will just work when you assign/set the value for the first time. Reassigning an already defined value would result i a 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error and I'm not sure if there's a workaround for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make the variables private and write getters and setters for them. In the setter you can check for the correct type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436948/3464036) for checking the type.

```
function Dude() {
    var firstName = '';
    var lastName = '';

    this.setFirstName = function(name) {
        if(typeof name == 'string' || name instanceof String) {
            firstName = name;
        }
    }
    this.getFirstName = function() {
        return firstName;
    }
};

var d = new Dude();
d.setFirstName('Ok mr');
d.setFirstName(100);

console.log(d.getFirstName()); // returns "Ok mr"
```

But pay attention: When you use the value of an input element or pass the name in quotes it will be a string. No matter wether it represents a number or not.

Reference: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to stick with this method. I was looking for a purer way to set and get values without the function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Dude() {
   this.firstName = '';
   this.lastName = '';

   Dude.prototype.setFirstName(name) = function() {
      if(typeof name != "string") this.firstName = name.toString();
      else this.firstName = name;
   };

   Dude.prototype.setLastName(name) = function() {
      if(typeof name != "string") this.lastName = name.toString();
      else this.lastName = name;
   };
}

var d = new Dude();
d.setFirstName("name");
d.setLastName(100);
```

These functions check whether the names are strings, if they aren't, the name will be converted to a string. This means it will then be assigned as string to either the firstName or lastName.

Comment: This doesn't protect against `d.lastName = 100;` which is part of what I think the OP is looking for.

Comment: That's nearly imposssible, you have to check that perpetually so thid is the best way to check ir

Comment: It's not impossible at all.  It can be done with [getters and setters](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/) in modern browsers or with the technique described in kekub's answer and [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).