# Check if all elements in array are strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a good way to check if all indexes in an array are strings?

```
check(["asd", 123]); // false
check(["asd", "dsa", "qwe"]); // true
```

Comment: @Compass All strings, even numeric.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string Tada

Comment: @Compass What do you mean, that's not the question?

Comment: @Murplyx If you have a concept of iteration and conditionals, knowing how to discern between a string and a number should be enough :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all elements are strings.

```js
const isStringsArray = arr => arr.every(i => typeof i === "string")

console.log( 
  isStringsArray(['a','b','c']),
  isStringsArray(['a','','c']),
  isStringsArray(['a', ,'c']),
  isStringsArray(['a', undefined,'c']),
  isStringsArray(['a','b',1]) 
)
```

Comment: Just in case, IE>8 :)

Comment: In lodash, `_.every(x, _.isString);`

Comment: here is a solution with .some() which will prevent you from going through all elements

`function allElementsAreString(arr => !arr.some(element => typeof element !== "string"))`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: @MattCatellier: both `some` and `every` are "short circuiting", meaning that they will stop as soon as the condition is not satisfied for `every` or as soon as it is satisfied for `some`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this - iterate through the array and test if everything is a string or not.

```
function check(arr) {
 for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   if(typeof arr[i] != "string") {
      return false;
    }
 }

 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var data = ["asd", 123];

function isAllString(data) {
    var stringCount;
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        if (typeof data[i] === 'string')
            stringCount++;
    }
    return (stringCount == data.length);
}

if (isAllString(data)) {
    alert('all string');
} else {
    alert('check failed');
}
```

Comment: @CambridgeMike version is far more efficient (:

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
check=function(a){
    for ( var i=0; i< a.length; i++ ) {
        if (typeof a[i] != "string")
            return false;
    };
    return true;
}
console.log(check(["asd","123"])); // returns true
console.log(check(["asd",123])); // returns false
```