# Don't want ISODate() with mongodb output

Tags: mongodb

I don't want ISODate() object with mongodb output. My mongo db contains Time key with ISODate().

```
{ '_id': ObjectId(''), 
 'Time': ISODate("2017-01-30T18:04:54.296Z") }
```

I Need my output as:

```
 { '_id': ObjectId(''), 
 'Time': "2017-01-30T18:04:54.296Z" }
```

What should i do to get time without ISODate()?

Comment: Can you be more precise about exactly what output you want, and in what datatype?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I have updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert mongodb ISODate to string in mongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560366/how-to-convert-mongodb-isodate-to-string-in-mongodb)