# array + charAt issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code output a `k[i].charAt is not a function` error. The strange thing is that there is no error - and the result is correct - if instead of `i` I put a number `k[1].charAt(0)`. Same thing with `indexOf`.

```
for (i = 0; n < arguments.length; i++) {
    k[i] = arguments[i];
    if (k[i].charAt(0) == "["){
        k[i] = eval(k[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `k`? your code doesnt include your definition of `k`.

Comment: What is `n`? Have you tried debugging this yourself, with `console.log` for example?

Comment: You don't seem to be updating n in your loop, so depending on what it is initially, this could go in an infinite loop. Also, your definitions of `k` and `n` are not given here.

Comment: N is a typing error, even changing with i the result does not change. k is a global array defined at the beginning with var k = []

Comment: Then you should of explained that in the question to make it less ambiguous and get better responses

Answer (score 0):

This code is kind of ambiguous.

1. `arguments` represents all arguments given to a function as array-like object.
2. `charAt` is a function defined on `String.prototype`

So `if (x.chatAt(0) == '[') { … }` will only work if `x` is a String, otherwise you will get the Error as described above.

All in all (in es6):

```
const foo = (...args) => {
  for (let arg of args) {
    if (arg.chatAt(0) == '[') { … }
  }
} 

foo({}) // Error
foo('[', {}) // Error, because arg2 is not a string
foo('[', ']') // No Errors, because each arg is a String
```

So there are two things you could do:

1. convert each arg to a string, before running the test:  `if (''+ arg.charAt(…)) …`, or `if (arg.toString().charAt())`
2. throw an Error if an Argument is not a string. To test if a variable is a String can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you hand over arguments, which are [JSON](http://json.org/) strings, then I suggest to use a mapping with a check and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and avoid to use `eval`.

```js
function convert() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function (a) {
        return a[0] === '[' ? JSON.parse(a) : a;
    });
}

console.log(convert('a', 1, '[1,2,3]'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```