# How can I convert my variable into a string?

Tags: jquery, string

I have a variable named `input` which is coming directly from a mySQL database.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(name,"(",id,")" SEPARATOR ",") AS data
```

When I test, if it is a string, then the output is "no"

```
 "render": function (data, type, row) {

    var input = data;

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(input) == '[object String]') {
      console.log("yes");
    } else {
      console.log("no");
   }
},
```

But I need the output to be "yes"...

I tested to convert the input `input.toString();`
But then I do not get any output at all

Comment: I edited your code to be in an exectuable snippet. As you can see it works fine. This means that your `input` variable *is not a string*. Are you sure it's not an array of strings?

Comment: When running your code in the console, I get the correct result: https://i.imgur.com/yjNBPrr.png

Comment: @nbokmans  Yes of course this code is working. But my variable is coming from a database and is not a string. This is my problem

Comment: @Jarla: How do you expect us to fix code that is working fine? Try posting code that doesn't work. i.e. the actual variable value that you *are* using

Comment: But is there no way to convert any input into a string?

Comment: If you select it correctly you shouldn't need to convert it at all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use String(param) function for converting your variable into a string.

**i.e.**

```
String(input);
```

Comment: What does this try to answer? `Object input` is not even valid JS.

Comment: Wonderful! This was exaclty what I was looking for!

Comment: @Jarla this is a bit of a hacky way to solve your problem. I'd suggest checking exactly what `input` ***is*** and where it's coming from. Sadly you gave us the irrelevant part of your code so we can't really help you with that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated my code, maybe now it is more clear.

Comment: Not really. That's the SQL. We need the JS code that retrieves it

Answer (score 2):

You could use `typeof` instead:

```js
var input = 'cat(13),dog(12),bird(14)';

if (typeof input === "string") {
   console.log('yes');
} else {
   console.log('no');
}
```

This question was already discussed here: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: While better code, this isn't what the OP is asking.

Comment: You can clearly see that the executable snippet gives the correct result. You are implementing it incorrectly. Show all your code.

Comment: Updated my question