# Can Ramda have isString?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

### Background

I am trying to use ramda and I need a pure function that lets me know if a given input is a string or not, much like lodash `_.isString`.

### Question

After searching everywhere I couldn't find anything in Ramda for this. So I wonder, is there a way, using any of Ramda's existing functions, that I can create a `isString` function?

I find this horribly limiting and is it is not possible i might just use lodash in the end :S

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `const isString = x => typeof x === 'string'` ?

Comment: just use `const isString = x => typeof x === 'string' && x instanceof String`

Comment: Or look at this answer for a more robust way of checking https://stackoverflow.com/a/17772086/2880747

Comment: So, what I conclude from your posts is that Ramda does not have such a function and neither can I compose it using Ramda tools. Is there a feedback channel where I can propose such a thing?

Comment: See my answer for how Ramda supplies this.  But you can ask questions on Ramda's [Gitter Channel](https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda) or raise issues on Ramda's [Issues page](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/new).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rather than have `isString`, `isObject`, `isArray`, `isFunction`, etc, Ramda simply provides **[`is`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#is)**, which you can use to create any of these you like:

```
const isString = R.is(String)
const isRectangle = R.is(Rectangle)

isString('foo') //=> true
isString(42) //=> false

isRectangle(new Rectangle(3, 5)) //=> true
isRectangle(new Square(7)) //=> true (if Rectangle is in the prototype chain of Square)
isRectangle(new Triangle(3, 4, 5)) //=> false
```

And you don't have to create the intermediate function.  You can just use it as is:

```
R.is(String, 'foo') //=> true
R.is(String, {a: 'foo'}) //=> false
```

Comment: Incredibly valuable output once again. You Sir, deserve all the juice from this upvote !

Answer (score 0):

this should also work `R.type(x) === "String"`

Answer (score -2):

If you're looking for predicate functions for ramda you should look into [ramda-adjunct](https://github.com/char0n/ramda-adjunct) library. The most popular and widely used extension to ramda, that comes with goodies ramda doesn't have, nor will never implement due to various reasons. I do maintain the library and we have have more than 25 contributors.

Regarding R.is, I would be careful with this function, it uses JavaScript **instanceof** operator under the hood. When inspecting objects from different JavaScript realms/envs e.g. IFrame, you may be surprised with the result of **R.is** return value.