# How to tell JS to only replace HTML if API request gave string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want JS to fill my span only if API gave an actual string for both fields. If it didn't then I want it to display default value only in one field. The default value is "Germany".

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=[APIKEY]", function (response) { 
    city = response.city;
    country_name = response.country_name;
    $("#city").html(city);
    $("#country_name").replaceWith(country_name);
  }, "jsonp"); 
});
```

```js
<span id="city"></span>
<span id="country_name">Germany</span>
```

Comment: Sounds like an `if` conditional

Comment: Check if the response is a string. If so set the default value to 'x', else set the default to 'y'.

Comment: `if (city && country_name) { ... }`

Comment: `if ( typeof city == 'string') { /* code here */ }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a variable is a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should use `text()` not `replaceWith()` to set the innerText of the `div`. Secondly, you can use `||` to coerce a value if it's `undefined`, `null`, an empty string or any other falsy value. Try this:

```
$("#city").text(city || '');
$("#country_name").text(country_name || 'Germany');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate both fields only if both fields are returned from the ajax request, you can simply wrap them in an if statement:

```
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=[APIKEY]", (response) => {

 if(response.city && response.country_name){
  // same code here
 }

});
```