# Object.split is not a function

Tags: angular

How do i fix the error `odd.split is not a function at Payment.redot` here is my code in typescript or ts, i am using angular.

```
  redot(odd){
    let o = odd.split('.');
    let decimal = '';
    if(typeof o[1] != 'undefined'){
      decimal = o[1];
      decimal = decimal.replace('%', '');
      if(decimal.length > 2){
        decimal = decimal.substr(0, 2) + '...%';
      } else {
        decimal += '%';
      }
    }
    return o[0] + '.' + decimal;
  }
```

Comment: what is the `odd` type?

Comment: what do you mean `odd` type?

Comment: percentage @WilliamWang

Comment: is it string?  what is the result of `console.log(odd)`

Comment: the result is 100, it is integer

Comment: odd is object, specify odd type: redot(odd: string){...

Answer (score 2):

[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is the method of String, so you need to convert `odd` to string

```
  redot(odd){
    let o = odd.toString().split('.');
    ....
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firat convert that as String

```
    redot(odd){
       //converAsString
        odd = odd.toString();
        let o = odd.split('.');
        let decimal = '';
        if(typeof o[1] != 'undefined'){
          decimal = o[1];
          decimal = decimal.replace('%', '');
          if(decimal.length > 2){
            decimal = decimal.substr(0, 2) + '...%';
          } else {
            decimal += '%';
          }
        }
        return o[0] + '.' + decimal;
      }
```

Comment: because if you want to use split it should be String

Answer (score 1):

You should check if odd is a string... try declaring its type in the function parameter.

```
redot(odd: string) {}
```

This error happens when you try to use an object function that does not exists.

Check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

I suggest to use typeof or instanceof for check if it is a string.

Check this: [Check if a variable is a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

make the most of typescript. Split can be used with string only.

if you define argument type, typescript immediately tell you the error and angular code will not compile either.

[image]

```js
function redot(odd: number): string {
  let o = odd ? odd.toString().split(".") : "";
  let decimal = "";
  if (o[1] != undefined) {
    decimal = o[1];
    decimal = decimal.replace("%", "");
    if (decimal.length > 2) {
      decimal = decimal.substr(0, 2) + "...%";
    } else {
      decimal += "%";
    }
    
  }
 return o[0] + (decimal ? `.${decimal}` : "");
}

console.log(redot(12));
console.log(redot(12.34));
console.log(redot(12.32334));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```